# Arcgis Pro 2.0 Jupyter Notebook Install Fails

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, arcgis

I did a fresh windows install of ArcGIS Pro 2.0 to a local user location. I then used the python package installer to install spyder and jupyter.

I launched jupyter notebook from the python command prompt that resides in the start menu for ArcGIS Pro.

Jupyter launches, but creating a new notebook always starts with a dead kernel. ipykernel is installed according to the ArcGIS pro python package manager. The kernel error message follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 516, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 75, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 307, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 94, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 257, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 203, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\rdchlbms\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've worked on this problem for a few days but I can't figure it out. I've looked at a number of posts that discuss connecting Jupyter and arcgis. They all make it appear possible if not easy, but this seems like a non-starter. What is missing, and why is the kernel starting dead? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you said it's dead kernel though python is installed , assuming everything ok (versions, etc) ,that's means jupyter didn't recognize the kernel yet

The error is matching that of: [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/300#issue-101282409)

I think it's mostly the same , sometimes the kernels json files for jupyter need to be created in some folder (in windows it were in `C:/Programs Data/Jupyter/..` ) before the first usage

launch the command (as admin):

`python -m Jupyter kernelspec install-self`

Then retry,

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, run the python command prompt with the following:

(gee) C:\Users\thapa\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\gee>
conda activate tensorflow1
conda install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --name tensorflow1 --user

Restart ArcGIS pro, now it will work.